# How to paste on each cell while using For each cell loop

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables, listobject

I have 2 columns A and B. I created a Sub loop to check if the value of cells in column 2 is <> "NULL" then if its not NULL I have to copy the valueof it and paste it to its counterpart row in Column A.

[image]

I tried this code but can't continue because I'm having a hard time pasting the value of the cell in column 2 to its left side column 1 counterpart it only paste in cell A2. How to paste it to every cell in the 1st column if the column 2 counterpart of it is not equal to NULL?

```
Sub IF_Loop()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("TablePrac[Department]")
        If cell.Value <> "NULL" Then
            cell.Copy Range("A2")
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: `Cell.offset(0, -1).value = cell.value`

Comment: Thank you very much!, will give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Values in Excel Table

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

- The key difference between the two solutions is that the first 'deals' with the rows and columns of the worksheet, while the second uses the table (`DataBodyRange`) rows and columns (seems kind of more appropriate).
- The '`cValue/CStr` business' avoids the type mismatch error occurring if there is an error value.
- Adjust the values in the constants section.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub TableColumns()
    
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    
    Const dColString As String = "Table1[Column1]"
    
    Const sColString As String = "Table1[Column2]"
    Const sCriteria As String = "NULL"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = ws.Range(dColString)
    drg.ClearContents
    Dim dCol As Long: dCol = drg.Column ' Worksheet Column
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Range(sColString)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim cValue As Variant
    
    For Each sCell In srg.Cells
        cValue = sCell.Value
        If CStr(cValue) <> sCriteria Then
            sCell.EntireRow.Columns(dCol).Value = sCell.Value ' Worksheet Row
        End If
    Next sCell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub TableColumnsRowRange()
    
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const tblName As String = "Table1"
    
    Const sColTitle As String = "Column2"
    Const sCriteria As String = "NULL"
    
    Const dColTitle As String = "Column1"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(tblName)
    
    Dim sCol As Long: sCol = tbl.ListColumns(sColTitle).Index ' Table Column
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dCol As Long
    With tbl.ListColumns(dColTitle)
        .DataBodyRange.ClearContents
         dCol = tbl.ListColumns(dColTitle).Index ' Table Column
    End With
    
    Dim srrg As Range
    Dim cValue As Variant
    
    For Each srrg In tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows ' Table (DataBodyRange) Row
        cValue = srrg.Cells(sCol).Value
        If CStr(cValue) <> sCriteria Then
            srrg.Cells(dCol).Value = srrg.Cells(sCol).Value
        End If
    Next srrg

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```